# Pandas - Category of Field Between Date Range

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like this:

```
      id  date_of_field_update status_prior_to_update status_after_update    
0    226       12/6/2017 16:46            Closed Lost           Discovery   
1    226       12/8/2017 14:56              Discovery            Proposal   
2   9792       12/7/2017 10:15                   Demo            Proposal   
3   9792       12/7/2017 10:14              Discovery                Demo   
4   9796       12/6/2017 12:33               Proposal        Finalization   
5   9796       1/16/2018 10:03           Finalization          Closed Won   
6   7426       1/17/2018 16:17        Initial Contact            Targeted   
7   7426       1/17/2018 16:25               Targeted           Discovery   
8   7426       1/29/2018 11:39              Discovery                Demo   
9   7426        1/30/2018 9:46                   Demo            Proposal   
10  1292       1/17/2018 14:48            Unqualified            Targeted   
11  1416      12/15/2017 12:39              Discovery            Targeted   
12  2475        1/3/2018 15:48            Closed Lost            Targeted   
13  2558      12/13/2017 10:21               Finalist            Proposal   
14  2558        1/5/2018 13:06               Proposal         Closed Lost
```

Each record represents a sales opportunity, the status of the opportunity (e.g. "Proposal" or "Demo"),  and the date at which the opportunity field was updated along with the before and after statuses of the field.

[Here](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/26546990/) on Pastebin is a Python list version of the above sample data.

How can a function be written that return the status of a specific `id` at an arbitrary date?

That is:

```
def get_opp_status(id, date):
    """Return status of given opp at given date"""
    # find status of opp at given date 
    return status
```

Updates:

- removed irrelevant `current_status` column from sample data.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: @Isma Fair suggestion - I guess I'm just stuck on this one, haven't really been able write anything that even remotely worked.

Comment: I generally advocate that users make an attempt first. But, in this case, it was just one or two lines and it would take more of my time to decipher an existing solution than to write my own.

Comment: Yep - I figured there would probably be a one-liner or something (one that a more advanced Pandas user than I would know) and my messy attempt at a solution wouldn't have been helpful to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way, assuming your date columns are ordered:

```
df['date_of_field_update'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_field_update'])

def get_opp_status(df, id, date):
    stat = df['status_after_update'][df['date_of_field_update'] <= date][df['id'] == id]
    if len(stat) > 0:
        return stat.iloc[-1]
    else:
        return df['status_prior_to_update'][df['id'] == id].iloc[0]

get_opp_status(df, 7426, pd.to_datetime('2019-01-17 16:24:00'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. I sort in advance so that it's only necessary to get the first item via a generator.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_field_update']).dt.normalize()
df = df.sort_values(['id', 'date_of_field_update'])

def get_opp_status(df, myid, mydate):
    return next(k for i, j, k in zip(df['id'], df['date'], df['current_status']) if j < mydate and i == myid)

get_opp_status(df, 226, pd.to_datetime('2017-12-10'))  # Proposal
```

Comment: but what if we wanted to find the status of `226` on 2017-12-10? Same answer but different input